# Is there is a specific original source where the "quantum operator ordering issue" is stated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, specific-reference, history

During my research, when the quantum operator ordering ambiguity is mentioned is deemed usually in the likes of "the well-known problem of ordering in quantum mechanics".

However, could anybody point me in the right direction as where to find an article or book where is first considered?

Comment: Usually it can be traced back to the van Hove-Groenewald "no go theorem" prohibiting quantization of arbitrary functions, but it may be older than that...

Comment: In point of fact "ambiguity" is the modern term, as ***it is not a problem*** anymore, after [Groenewold's 1946 thesis paper](http://www.rug.nl/research/vsi/events/groenewold/groenewold-article.pdf). It was a problem of "quantization", the alchemical problem of specifying a *unique* quantum theory with a given classical limit, in contrast to a family of such.

Answer (score 1):

Dirac already considered it in a [1925 paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098%2Frspa.1925.0150)(Open access). (Thanks to [Alex Nelson](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/9290/alex-nelson) for the [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/117337/is-there-is-a-specific-original-source-where-the-quantum-operator-ordering-issu#comment240568_117337) to the OP's question. I found it at the Wikipedia's article on [Groenewold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbrand_J._Groenewold). =])

Operator ordering issue also exists in path-integral formalism, and of course Feynman was aware of it. See for example "Techniques and applications of path integration" by Schulman.

Let me add my personal impression:

1. But isn't it natural to assume such question has existed from the very beginning of the QM?
2. Caution: If you're a student learnig QM, I recommend you not to be distracted by such issues, which is likely to waste your time. Just learn to how to use QM.

Comment: Suggestion to the answer (v1): As an aid to the reader consider pointing out the page in the 1925 paper where Dirac discusses the quantum operator ordering ambiguity.